# HTML Design is not loading in silverlight Page

Tags: html, silverlight-4.0

I using silverlight

I have a button in silverlight page1 on click of button I am calling another silverlight page2 inside this silvelight page2 I am calling HTML Page

When I call like this HTML design is not loading..

Comment: Provide some code dude...

Comment: you shoud use browser control in your page!!!